# C++ Get Clipboard - special characters

Tags: c++, unicode

I have a simple function that is used to retrieve text from clipboard and print it to file. It works fine unless a foreign letter is in clipboard. For example letter "ń" wouldn't be printed out. Here is the code with some obvious parts omitted:

```
HANDLE hData = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT);
if (hData != NULL)
{
    wchar_t * pszText = static_cast<wchar_t*>(GlobalLock(hData));
    if (pszText != NULL)
    {
        std::wstring text(pszText);

        // Release the lock
        GlobalUnlock(hData);

        // Release the clipboard
        CloseClipboard();

        //myFile is a wofstream.
        myFile << text;
    }
}
```

What I tried:

1. I used "wcout" as well as standard "cout" to print out variables "text" and "pszText". In both cases, the special letter wasnt printed out.
2. Tried changing CF_UNICODETEXT to CF_TEXT and same result.

---

TL:DR I have a get clipboard function but it doesnt work with characters like "ń" or "ć".

---

**Edit:** As suggested, I checked the variable in the debugger. It turns out that the variable "wstring text" actually contains the special character e.g. "ń". The problem seems to be with writing to the file. Is there some special way file needs to be opened before special characters can be written? Below is how I open the file.

```
myFile.open(logFullPath, std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::app);
```

**Edit2:**
Im 100% positive now that the problem is this line:

```
//myFile is a wofstream.
myFile << text;
```

Comment: Have you looked at the characters in a debugger? Alternatively try dumping the codepoints of the received characters. Window console is known for not handling non-ASCII character sets very well, to put it softly.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but aren't you calling `CloseClipboard` in the wrong scope? If you can't get the clipboard data, then you will have a resource leak as you don't close the clipboard.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I didnt copy the whole source code. The issue you described is not present in my full version.

Comment: @rodrigo I just tried what you suggested and I will post findings in the main post.

Comment: I think that the problem may not be in writing the file, but in looking at it later. You can try writing the BOM (U+FEFF) just at the beginning of the file. Then Notead and other editors will automatically detect that it is a Unicode file: `myFile << L'\uFEFF';`. Note that you should not do this if you are appending to the file. Alternatively, use the "Open As" and "Unicode" in your text editor.

Comment: @rodrigo I dont think so. I check the text file and its always 0 bytes. I would understand not seeing characters in notepad but I can tell that the file is actually empty.

Comment: 0 bytes?! That's weird. Are you closing the file after writing? Or at least flushing it?

Comment: @rodrigo Yes, I close the file. Normally file closes after a certain number of writes but for testing purposes I added myFile.close() just after "myFile << text". Remember that it works flawlessly without special characters.

Comment: When you say "the variable `wstring text` actually contains the special character e.g. 'ń'", what is the exact byte sequence, i.e. what encoding is that character in? If the various environments involved disagree on the encoding, you might be looking at a conversion error. Having a minimal **compilable** example would be helpful. Perhaps initializing `text` with a literal instead of going through that (apparently unrelated) clipboard stuff?

Answer (score 0):

The following code is an example how to deal with the above problem of writing unicode characters to ofstream. Using this solved all of my issues so far.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
    std::wofstream mystream("test.txt");
    mystream.imbue(std::locale(std::locale(),
                   new std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::codecvt_mode(std::consume_header|std::generate_header)>));
    mystream << "Hello, World!\n";
}
```